# Can I recover lost saves?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just updated Minecraft Beta from 1.2_01 to 1.2_02 and my saves (I had only one world) seem lost.

Is it possible try to recover it in some way?

Comment: Minecraft is semi-unstable for me lately.  I have a script that makes a copy of C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\saves every day, a good backup makes recovery far easier.

Comment: Good suggestion, I will follow it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be able to recover it using some of the techniques that are used when the files go missing in power outages. All credit goes to the origional poster, this is located on the minecraft offical forums. I am unsure if this works for upgrade losses but id imagine the backup would still be there unless you have played to the point it recreated? You may be able to check %appdata%.minecraft\saves
and see if your world still exists on that side for the recovery attempt.

Tutorial: How to restore missing world after system crash
http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=51286

Wish i could be more specific, reply here if you need help or have any concerns.

Comment: It is always best to quote the required steps using `>` (but still providing the link of course) so one does not have to follow links (that may someday not work for one reason or other)

Comment: its rather long I was hoping to avoid a huge post for something I wasnt 100% on. No worries Ill keep this in mind as sound advice.

Comment: @Tobias - don't quote *too* extensively though. Stack Exchange doesn't want to fall foul of copyright restrictions.

Comment: @ChrisF: true, copyright issues should be checked first of course, didn't think of that...

Comment: I read the topic and I tried deleting level.dat and replacing with one of a new world just created, and removing the most recent numeric sub-folder and it worked. I lost all things I carried with me, but better then nothing :)